# SelectNodes Error

Tags: c#, html, xaml

i want to get this in html

```
<div id="lyrics-body-text">
<p class='verse'>It's been a long and winding journey<br/>
But I'm finally here tonight picking up the pieces<br/>
And walking back into the night into the sunset of your glory<br/>
When my heart and future lies there's nothing like that feeling<br/>
When I look into your eyes</p></div>
```

using `C#` and `XAML` and i use also `HtmlAGilityPack`
Here my code:

```
HttpClient wClient = new HttpClient();
responseData = await wClient.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
String Lyrics = utf8.GetString(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);

StringBuilder pureText = new StringBuilder();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Lyrics);

try
{
     foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='lyrics-body-text']")) // error
     {
           pureText.Append(node.InnerText);
     }
}
catch
{ }

return pureText.ToString();
```

Here's the Error:

> 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for
>   'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's difficult to test. However, try replacing `DocumentNode.SelectNodes` with `DocumentElement.SelectNodes`.

From the HtmlAgilityPack documentation sample code:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"]))
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: If you mean the example code has an error, I notice that they omitted a closed paren in the documentation. I've fixed this now.

Comment: SelectNodes is not working in my program. I want to get a specific data in html which is lyrics of a song. I saw example of getting a specific data in html thats why i copied it but it as an error.